# Can I fill Russian documents in Latin script?

Tags: paperwork, russia

Say I want to travel to Russia on tourist visa, physically visit some Russian bank and open a new account in roubles.
Let's say my name is John Doe. Do I write "John Doe" or "Джон Доу" in bank agreement papers?

Comment: Even though the premise of your question is "on a tourist visa", it seems like this might be better answered over on the [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: Perhaps the first part of this question should be ‘Can a tourist open a bank account in Russia’?

Comment: "Do I write "John Doe" or "Джон Доу" in bank agreement papers?": Ask the bank what they want.

Comment: I have entered several kinds of contracts in countries using Cyrillic script, but I don't think I've ever filled out a form. I've always just shown my id/passport and the counterpart filled out the contract on a computer and then made a printout for me to sign. Isn't that what you would expect in a Russian bank as well? FWIW, I guess Latin and Cyrillic script has been used roughly 50/50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of legal documents *at a minimum* are going to be checked against your passport and whatever other documents they may require in order to authenticate your identity. So, fill it out with exactly the name that your passport has.

There might be a need for other documents- can’t really comment directly on what they may be, but in general there might be a need for a certified translation or additional certifications.